# jQuery Scroll the over flow

Tags: jquery, scroll, mouseevent

I want to create a flash type scroll effect where on mouse over of a button the text which is overflowing in the div shows up by scrolling down.

http://uniquedl.com/3closets/about.html

the text

> Fashion is omnipresent!
>
> From offices to neighborhoods and
>   streets to social circles. You can
>   choose to ignore it, but it's
>   impossible to get away from it.
>   Constantly upping the fashion quotient
>   is an active agenda for most and a
>   passive one for the rest. You wish you
>   had more time to discover novel
>   brands, hard to obtain products and
>   better deals. Sometimes you just wish
>   for more….

should be scrollable on the above link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#)?

Comment: i tried to implement it. but looks like they need to have their own css. and not sure how to define my own buttons for scolling

Comment: Will the simple CSS property of `overflow-y:scroll;` not suffice?

Comment: Did you download this css file of theirs? http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/style/jquery.jscrollpane.css In there you should be able to define your own buttons.

Comment: Check under the download section if you need anything else: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/#usage

Comment: Try using the exact same class they are using: **scroll-pane** and activate it using this jQuery call: `$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();`, maybe their code needs specific classes. You also **need** to specify the element's `overflow:auto`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the height of the div to an appropriate height, probably using the jQuery animate function.

```
$('#button_id').mouseover(function() {
  $('#div_id').animate({
    height: +=400,
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

To determine an appropriate height, you could determine the height of the child p tags and then add a buffer, eg

```
var height = 0;
$('#div_id p').each(function(index){ target_height += $(this).height()});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I'm not sure this is what he asked for… I believe there is a way scroll the text without tampering with the height.

Comment: yeah Anriette is right. i have a div which is say 400px. i will have few para of text which will take 800px. when i click down. it should slowly scroll the text to the bottom while the top text hides and vice versa